# Maintain SEO of a website while migrating it to Wordpress?

Tags: seo, migration

i have a site url http://www.dualfocusphotography.co.uk

i want to convert it to wordpress in such a way its SEO or site ranking should not be disturbed.

any one guide me is it possible if yes then how?

any help or relevant-materiel would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to create a theme that contains the exact same structure as your current site.

Then you need to go to great lengths to keep WordPress form adding stuff that is intended to make your site more SEO friendly - but you said you don't want to have your SEO disturbed - positive or negative disturbance. :-)

So you're going to need to be vigilant because by default there's good stuff output by WordPress to help your site index better.

Comment: I'll piggy back on this answer and just mention that if you're also switching technology platforms (for example, coming from a .NET site or previously serving actual .htm or .php files) then you'll want to be sure you do 301 redirects from page to page. I ran into this and solved it with this plugin: [Quick Page/Post Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) because it'll do nice relative url mapping and it'll handle aspx extensions.  Other than that, keep the structure and content the same as Sterling suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is with the URL's, you can use 301 redirects to maintain ranking. You can use either the [Simple 301 Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) plugin or do it manually in the .htaccess file. You can also use a plugin such as SEO Ultimate to monitor 404 errors throughout the site.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Google search on SEO shopping cart. 
I use Ascender Cart on my web site with fabulous results. Its SEO far exceeds the others.
As a new business, SEO should be one of your main concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a step by step guide here
https://ilocalsearch.net/wordpress-how-to-take-a-non-wordpress-website-and-rebuild-in-wordpress-maintaining-the-seo